# Convert SQL where clause to regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following SQL statement:

```
# WHERE
field LIKE '%ig%' AND field LIKE '%ru%'
```

What would be the correct way to translate this to a regex? My thought was because the ordering (in sql) doesn't matter, it'd each AND-ed `%term%` would translate to a positive lookahead:

```
(?=.*ig)(?=.*ru).+
```

Is there a better approach to this or is that normally how the above is translated?

Comment: Anchor the match at the start of the string, add `^` at the start. It is not necessary if you use `re.search` or `re.match` though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew out of curiosity, why are anchors important here if it's just a wildcard match on the entire text string?

Comment: See [***Lookarounds (Usually) Want to be Anchored***](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#anchor).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, but that website has some screwed-up font colors that I can't really read...could you provide the gist of it?

Comment: If the regex method tests each position inside a string, there will be redundant overhead. If you use a single matching method, it is OK to omit the `^` anchor.